# Group by day and month two different list with different year

Tags: c#, linq

Hi guys I need some help with LINQ, I am trying to show in a table the data of a year together with the data of the last year, but I cannot get it together in the same data model, for example: I collect the data from 03/08/2019 to 03/08/2021
and then the same but with a previous year, that is, 03/08/2018 until 03/08/2020, once this is stored in the same model with the `Date`, `Price`, `PrevDate` and `PrevPrice` fields.

[image: Something like that]

I have all the data between 03/08/2019 to 03/08/2021 in one `List` and the data in range of 03/08/2018 until 03/08/2020 in another `List<Model>`. How can I group in one single list with every model like this:

```cs
    Date = x.Date
    Price = x.TotalPrice
    PrevDate= x.PrevDate
    PrevPrice = x.PrevPrice
```

Well i have the next code: (groupact is the list in first range and Groupant is the 2nd list with the 2nd range of years that they are 1Y less than groupact list.

```cs
    var finalQuery = groupact.Union(groupant);
    var groupFilter = finalQuery.GroupBy(x => new { x.Fecha.Day, x.Fecha.Month }).ToList();
         int higherDateYear = groupFilter.Select(x => x.Select(y => y.Fecha.Year).Max()).FirstOrDefault();
        
        var group = groupFilter.Select(f => new
                        {
                            Fecha = DateTime.Parse(string.Format("{0}/{1}/{2}", f.Key.Day, f.Key.Month, higherDateYear)),
                            Total = f.Sum(x => x.Total),
                            TotalAnterior = f.Sum(x => x.TotalAnterior),
                        });
        
                        resultado = group.Select(x => new ComparativoVentaModel()
                        {
                            Total = x.Total,
                            TotalAnterior = x.TotalAnterior,
                            Comparativo = x.TotalAnterior != 0 ? ((x.Total - x.TotalAnterior) / x.TotalAnterior) * 100 : 100,
                            Fecha = x.Fecha
                        }).ToList();
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: i tried to make an Union between both list, just like that: `var finalQuery = groupact.Union(groupant); 
` and then group by day and month with the next code:                `var groupFilter = groupact.GroupBy(x => new { x.Fecha.Day, x.Fecha.Month }).ToList();`

Comment: You may want to use a more specific date format in your question.  Does `03/08/2019` mean 3-Aug-2019 or 8-Mar-2019?

Comment: nono i don't want to print August or other month, just group both list and print the diference between one year and last year

Comment: Are the `PrevDate` and `LastDate` synonymous, or denote different dates? And what about the `Date` field?

Comment: Yes, sorry LastDate is the same as PrevDate, Date is just the current year range that i am consulting. LastDate is Date.Year - 1

Comment: Not sure you need to group the lists - You could just populate another list with custom objects that contain the properties you need from both lists. Would that work?

Comment: How do the properties of the object you're selecting (`Total`, `TotalAnterior`, `Comparativo`, `Fecha`) map to the data you want to display (`Date`, `Price`, `PrevDate`, `PrevPrice`)?

Comment: The table is just an example, i want to display the fields that i post in code `Fecha, Total, TotalAnterior, Comaparativo`